# Store ArrayList of Students in File using TextFields

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I made a small java swing application to store list of students in a file `students.txt`. 
But I am facing a problem while saving many students into the file: 
when I click the "save" button, only one student record is stored. If I input new data in the text fields and click save button again it saves only newly created student, overwriting older records, while I want a new student to be appended to the existing student list in a file.

Here is my code :

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class studentTest extends JFrame {

    JPanel p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6;
    JTextField f1, f2, f3, f4;
    JLabel l1, l2, l3, l4;
    JButton b1, b2, b3;

    public studentTest() {
        setBounds(100, 150, 300, 400);
        b1 = new JButton("Save");
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                List<Student> Students = new ArrayList();
                Student newStudents = new Student();
                newStudents.setStudentFName(f1.getText());
                newStudents.setStudentLName(f2.getText());
                newStudents.setGPA(f4.getText());
                newStudents.setID(f3.getText());
                Students.add(newStudents);

                        try{

                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/Users/Yukki/Desktop/Students.txt"));
                        pw.println(newStudents+"\n"); 
                        pw.close();

                        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {

                        }

                    }

        });
        b2 = new JButton("First Record");
        b3 = new JButton("Next");
        l1 = new JLabel("  FirstName :");
        l2 = new JLabel("  LastName :");
        l3 = new JLabel("  ID :");
        l4 = new JLabel("  GPA :");
        f1 = new JTextField(10);
        f2 = new JTextField(10);
        f3 = new JTextField(10);
        f4 = new JTextField(10);
        p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        p1.add(l1);
        p1.add(f1);
        p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        p2.add(l2);
        p2.add(f2);
        p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        p3.add(l3);
        p3.add(f3);
        p4 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        p4.add(l4);
        p4.add(f4);
        p5 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        p5.add(b1);
        p6 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        p6.add(b2);
        p6.add(b3);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));
        add(p1);
        add(p2);
        add(p3);
        add(p4);
        add(p5);
        add(p6);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new studentTest()).show();



    }
}
```

Comment: You have many things in that code that is difficult where begin, but 1st) Follow java code convention, classes name start with uppercase, 2nd)Don't make never empties catchs 3rd) Is there a good reason to extend JFrame. 4th) You are creating every time `actionPerformed` an arrayList of one student and do nothing with it, you only save one student per event.

Comment: its just a test of my java project , it didn't finish yet ! and i just want to get the idea of creating multiple students in array list ! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are a number of of solutions you could try, I would recommend. Trying to use [Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/), as it will allow you to define the means by which a instance of Student can be out putted to XML.

From there, it should allow you to add multiple instances to the same file.

It might be suggested that you serialise the objects, but personally, I'd avoid it. It was only intended to be used for the short term storage of an object, typically for transmission over the wire, but that's just my opinion...

**Update with example...**

This is based on the examples from [JAXB exmaple: Marshalling and Unmarshalling list or set of objects](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/07/30/jaxb-exmaple-marshalling-and-unmarshalling-list-or-set-of-objects/) and [JAXB Hello World Example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)

First, we need to define the `Student` class and JAXB annotations.  This allows us to describe how instances of the object should be marshalled (translated)

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Student {

    String name;
    int age;
    int id;

    // This is a requirement of JAXB...
    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(int id, String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Next, we need to create a simple wrapper class that can contain a list of objects.  This is required so that the JAXB API can gain access to the internal data more easily...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Students implements Iterable<Student> {

    private List<Student> students;

    public Students() {
        this.students = new ArrayList<>(25);
    }

    public Student get(int index) {
        return students.get(index);
    }

    public void add(Student student) {
        students.add(student);
    }

    public void remove(Student student) {
        students.remove(student);
    }

    public int size() {
        return students.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "List-o-Students: " + size();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Student> iterator() {
        return students.iterator();
    }

}
```

Then, finally, we need to test it...

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import org.jaxb.test.Student;
import org.jaxb.test.Students;

public class JAXBExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Students students = new Students();
        students.add(new Student(100, "Bob", 29));
        students.add(new Student(101, "John", 19));
        students.add(new Student(102, "Joe", 39));
        students.add(new Student(103, "Jane", 25));

        try {

            File file = new File("file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Students.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(students, file);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(students, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            File file = new File("file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Students.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            students = (Students) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(students);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Which outputs...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<students>
    <students id="100">
        <age>29</age>
        <name>Bob</name>
    </students>
    <students id="101">
        <age>19</age>
        <name>John</name>
    </students>
    <students id="102">
        <age>39</age>
        <name>Joe</name>
    </students>
    <students id="103">
        <age>25</age>
        <name>Jane</name>
    </students>
</students>
List-o-Students: 4
```

**Updated with updatable example**

The following allows you to dynamically update the XML overtime.  It pretty much the same concept as read, write, read, but provides some additional functionality...

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    File xml = new File("file.xml");
    Document document = db.parse(xml);

     // Create a new context...
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Students.class);

    // Create a new Binder from the context
    Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();
    // Load the document
    Students students = (Students) binder.unmarshal(document);

    // Update the student at position 0
    Student student = students.get(0);
    student.setAge(100);

    // Add a new student
    students.add(new Student(200, "Harry", 65));

    // Update the document
    binder.updateXML(students);

    // Write the contents back to the file..
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        fos = new FileOutputStream(xml);
        t.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(fos));
    } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError | TransformerException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
} catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | JAXBException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

This might look a little complex, but it means you can now dynamically modify the underlying document.

For your needs though, I would simply read the existing list in at the start, update the list and finally, when you're ready, write it back...but that's just me...

And finally, a fully runnable example...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.Binder;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.jaxb.test.Student;
import org.jaxb.test.Students;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class JAXBExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Students students = new Students();
        students.add(new Student(100, "Bob", 29));
        students.add(new Student(101, "John", 19));
        students.add(new Student(102, "Joe", 39));
        students.add(new Student(103, "Jane", 25));

        write(students);
        students = null;
        students = read();

        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println(student);
        }

        update();

        students = null;
        students = read();

        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println(student);
        }

    }

    public static void write(Students students) {

        System.out.println("----> Write");
        try {

            File file = new File("file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Students.class);
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // output pretty printed
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(students, file);
//            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(students, System.out);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static Students read() {

        System.out.println("----< Read");
        Students students = null;
        try {

            File file = new File("file.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Students.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            students = (Students) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            System.out.println(students);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return students;

    }

    public static void update() {

        System.out.println("----> Update");
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            File xml = new File("file.xml");
            Document document = db.parse(xml);

            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Students.class);

            Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();
            Students students = (Students) binder.unmarshal(document);

            Student student = students.get(0);
            student.setAge(100);

            students.add(new Student(200, "Harry", 65));

            binder.updateXML(students);

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
                fos = new FileOutputStream(xml);
                t.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(fos));
            } catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError | TransformerException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    fos.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | JAXBException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: While I'm not 100% sure! I think that JAXB uses XMLEncoder at its heart, but simply makes it easier to deflate and inflate objects because you can simply defining the bindings between the object and the XML through annotations.

Comment: :O, but whatever i think  OP is lost, and need another type of answer, he use `setBounds()` also `show()` creates an arrayList of one object and do nothing, empty catch() etc.. i know you can do better :D (the same you say me a couple a week ago xD)

Comment: The OP uses setBounds on a frame  which is the same as using setSize and setLocation. While I agree, generously, pack is better, it's not complete sin to do this on a window ;) I've also not had my first cup of tea and I'm watching Peppa Pig with my daughter, so I'm only focusing on the immediate issues. Beside, you've already commented on the, ;)

Comment: You have to love the courage of people who down vote without comment. It fails to educate either the poster (me) or others as how to improve this or other answers in the future...

Comment: im not the downvoter but i don't think this answer solves op issues ;)

Comment: Other then the "other" coding issues, how couldn't this be used to write a list of objects to an external source?

Comment: Could be a more flexible solution , but he want to store in a `students.txt`, perhaps is in school.. and he post code what he try to do.. so i think that answer should be focus on that and a side note could add to use jaxb.. but as i said im not the downvoter and not the upvoter xD

Comment: @nachokk at least you make the effort to comment ;)

Comment: @nachokk Personally, I don't think the destination, per say, is a requirement, it's just what the OP has completed up to now and isn't stated as a requirement, this is just my opinion though ;)

Comment: by the way , I'm not at school ! but I'm trying to understand how array list works thats all ! just trying to learn how to make array of objects !

Comment: @MadProgrammer see, he is trying to understand how arraylist work, and you suggest go with jaxb specification that's my point :)

Comment: @Kaito madprogrammer is one of the best here follow his advices :)

Comment: @nachokk sure i will :)

Comment: @nachokk You're probably right, I simply saw the question as writing a list of objects to a file. Without messing about with creating your own read/write methods/protocols, this seemed like the easiest solution I knew of. Once my daughter has finished eating my breakfast, I'll  see if I can expand the answer ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer your way is very good , but may i ask u a question , how can i create many objects … for example when i enter the first student name and … it stored in the first line , then the second data in the second line and the third ... like its dynamically stored ! what do you think ? and the data is entered by the user not manually !

Comment: Instead of creating a `List` within the `actionPerformed` method, create an instance field and simply continue adding the `Student`s to that list.  When you're ready, write the contents out to a file.

Comment: @Kaito I've just looked how to append to the file but I need to test it. I will try and post it later

Comment: @MadProgrammer sure,no problem i will be waiting … take your time

Comment: I've updated the examples. Basically there is update method which can append new values into the document, but I'm not sure if it adds much more, as you could simply read the document, update the list and then write it back again, but hay, at least now you have options. Beware, I've updated the `Students` container ;)

Answer (score 1):

"newStudents" is just an Student instance. Iterate the list and write each item. (list name should begin with a simple letter btw). Also you are adding just one Student to the list.

```
for (Student student: students) {
    pw.println(student);
}
```

You can override toString() of student to get a meaningful string representation.

Comment: but i used as you said it also print the last saved student why is that :PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/Users/Yukki/Desktop/Students.txt"));
                        for (Student student: Students) {
                         pw.println(student);
                            }
                        pw.close();